# Ubuntu VPN Outside Network Connection Issue

Tags: networking, 13.10, 14.04, network-manager, vpn

I am having a strange issue when connecting to my VPN.
It kicks me off the internet.

I have it setup in 'Network Settings' (due to that is the only way I was able to get it to work)

Now, while I am able to access my network files that lie on the VPN (the 10.X.X.X addresses), I am also able to access files on my local network (my 192.X.X.X addresses), I am not able to go to http://www.google.com, or do anything for that matter outside my local and VPN networks.

I do notice an extra icon showing the VPN is connected, but there is another one I though was my LAN icon that has an X on it.

How can I do this?   I need to be able to connect to my VPN, and still have outside access?

**Route - no VPN Connection**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

**Route - with VPN Connection**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.10.10.120    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
mail.emagineusa 192.168.2.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
mail.emagineusa 192.168.2.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

**Host - google.com**

```
google.com has address 74.125.226.64
google.com has address 74.125.226.69
google.com has address 74.125.226.71
google.com has address 74.125.226.66
google.com has address 74.125.226.65
google.com has address 74.125.226.72
google.com has address 74.125.226.78
google.com has address 74.125.226.73
google.com has address 74.125.226.70
google.com has address 74.125.226.67
google.com has address 74.125.226.68
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4006:808::1006
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

**Traceroute to 8.8.8.8**

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.10.10.120 (10.10.10.120)  46.576 ms  50.601 ms  51.521 ms
 2  L300.BSTNMA-VFTTP-81.verizon-gni.net (98.110.197.1)  52.778 ms  53.686 ms  53.706 ms
 3  G0-14-2-0.BSTNMA-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net (130.81.218.198)  56.615 ms  61.274 ms  62.174 ms
 4  ae9-0.BOS-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net (130.81.163.164)  57.436 ms * *
 5  * * *
 6  * 0.xe-8-3-0.GW13.NYC1.ALTER.NET (152.63.5.1)  62.251 ms 0.xe-8-1-0.GW13.NYC1.ALTER.NET (152.63.4.133)  59.390 ms
 7  204.148.18.206 (204.148.18.206)  63.106 ms  66.221 ms  63.127 ms
 8  209.85.247.7 (209.85.247.7)  66.184 ms  67.259 ms  66.149 ms
 9  72.14.236.206 (72.14.236.206)  62.044 ms 209.85.252.242 (209.85.252.242)  64.209 ms 209.85.252.250 (209.85.252.250)  65.193 ms
10  72.14.239.93 (72.14.239.93)  65.624 ms 209.85.249.11 (209.85.249.11)  68.308 ms 72.14.239.93 (72.14.239.93)  70.615 ms
11  66.249.95.229 (66.249.95.229)  78.416 ms 72.14.235.10 (72.14.235.10)  78.483 ms 64.233.174.11 (64.233.174.11)  77.413 ms
12  72.14.234.65 (72.14.234.65)  77.720 ms  78.676 ms 72.14.234.55 (72.14.234.55)  79.552 ms
13  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  74.189 ms  74.678 ms  75.782 ms
```

Comment: Can you post output from command `route` when is vpn connected. Also put output from `host google.com` and `traceroute 8.8.8.8` when your vpn is connected

Comment: added to question.  Seems like all traffic is getting routed through the VPN.  Now, when I change the setting under 'Routes' in the IPv4 tab to 'Use this connection only for resources on its network', I can get back online, and there are no errors connecting to the VPN, but I am unable to access anything on the VPN

Answer (score 1):

I only can propose the script in witch you can add route or host to router traffic via ppp0 interface ...

Try maybe will work good.
Create file with some name and put in

```
nano name_of_script
```

script

```
 #!/bin/bash
function routeadd {
    route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
    route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
}
function makepptp {
   echo pty \"pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
pppd call vpn &
}
if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
else
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
fi

if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
    then
    rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
else
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
fi
```

In script change you host ip and add network or/and host witch you wish to connect via vpn

Usage:

```
sudo /path_to_script/name_of_script username password
```

note: set execute permision to script

In this way you have control over traffic.

Edit 1

Your server witch you want to access via vpn is on 10.10.10.10
Your vpn server is on 172.16.16.16

You change script to look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
    function routeadd {
        route add -host 10.10.10.10 dev ppp0
    }
    function makepptp {
       echo pty \"pptp 172.16.16.16 --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
       echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
       echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
       echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
       echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    pppd call vpn &
    }
    if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
            then
            rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
        echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
    else
        echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
    fi

    if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
        echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
        makepptp;
        sleep 8;
        routeadd;
    else
        echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
        makepptp;
        sleep 8;
        routeadd;
    fi
```

Comment: so I would just dump the connection from 'Network Manager'?   And use this instead?

Comment: sorry, but can you be a little more specific with what you mean by `In script change you host ip and add network or/and host witch you wish to connect via vpn`     what would go where?

Comment: and sorry for asking, but is there a way in this to check `if` the connection was indeed made?

Comment: Yes, don't start vpn connection from Network Manager. Create script and start vpn using it. On the begining of the script you have `function routeadd` Simple change in `route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0` for example `route add -net 10.0.0.0/16 dev ppp0` if you wish to access network `10.0.0.0/16` via vpn. Also you can access only specific host via vpn if you use command `route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0`. Next in section `function makepptp` you must change `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with ip address of vpn server. Only traffic srecified in script will be router via vpn

Comment: Thanks, but do I also put the VPN IP here?  `route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0`

Comment: No, address of vpn server put only in sector of `function makepptp`

Comment: Ok, so I don't understand the `route add -host`, and what I am supposed to do with it

Comment: If you use vpn to access servers/host on network 10.0.0.0/16 you don't use `route add -host`. You can simple delete that line or on begining put `#`. Script you can use on different ways, to route all to ppp0 interface, to add route to specific host, to add route to specific network.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this... I do not want to route all traffic through the VPN... that's why I asked this question...   I know very little about Networking on Linux... so please... bear with me...

Comment: I'm also getting an error on `route add -net` line stating `route: netmask doesn't match route address`

Comment: You have edit 1 with example

Comment: now I am getting: `SIOCADDRT: No such device`, and the script just hangs

Comment: Meybe you have some pptp process from succeeded connection. Try `sudo ps -ax | grep pptp` and kill all pptp before starting script again. Process kill with command `sudo kill -9 PID_of_process` Also start script with `sudo` like I wrote.

Comment: `11134 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto pptp`

Comment: killed all related processes, and no difference, still shows the same error